# How to do partial template class specialization with concept and requires?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

It's easy to write template function override with concept, but I don't know how to write template class partial specialization :(

```
template <typename T>
concept Integral = is_integral_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept IsNotIntegral = !
is_integral_v<T>;

template <typename T>
class Test
{
};

template <Integral T> // wrong
class Test
{
};

template <typename T> // wrong
    requires Integral<T>
class Test
{
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> t;
}
```

This doesn't work either:(

```
template <Integral T>
class Test
{
};

template <IsNotIntegral T>
class Test
{
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Both

```
template <Integral T> // wrong
class Test
{
};
```

and

```
template <typename T> // wrong
    requires Integral<T>
class Test
{
};
```

are using the declaration syntax of a *primary class template*, not a partial specialization. Compare the syntax of an unconstrained partial specialization from before concepts:

```
// primary class template
template <typename T>
class Test
{
};

// partial specialization of the class template
template <typename T>
class Test<T*>
{
};
```

The difference is that there isn't just a class name in the partial specialization after the `class` keyword, but a *template-id* `Test<T*>` instead. Without it a partial specialization makes no sense since we wouldn't know what template arguments we are specializing for.

So with constraints the syntax for a partial specialization should be the same:

```
template <Integral T>
class Test<T>
{
};
```

or

```
template <typename T>
    requires Integral<T>
class Test<T>
{
};
```